# MySql ODBC connection in VB6 on WinXP VERY slow. Other machines on same network are fast

Tags: mysql, vb6, string, odbc, connection

I have a VB6 application that has been performing very well. Recently, we upgraded our server to a Windows 2003 server. Migration of the databases and shares went well and we experienced no problems. Except one. And it has happened at multiple sites.

I use the MySQL ODBC 5.1 connector to point to my MySQL database. On identical machines (as far as I can tell, they are client machines not ours), access to the DB is lightning fast on all but one computer. They use the same software and have the same connection strings. And I'm sure it's not the program, but the ODBC connection. When I press the 'Test Connection' button in the ODBC connection string window, it can take up to 10 seconds on the poorly performing machine to respond with a success. All the other computers are instantaneous.

I have tried using ip address versus the machine name in the UDL, no change. I enabled option 256, which sped it up initially, but it's slow again. Most of the time on a restart the program will be fast for an hour or so then go slow again with the option 256 enabled.

Frankly, I am out of ideas and willing to entertain any and all ideas or suggestions. This is getting pretty frustrating. Anyone ever experience anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being a reverse dns problem. I added the slow computer to the host file on the server and everything is good!

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option to stop mysql doing these dns lookups on the server. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/dns.html